# Combinatorics of sports outcomes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I am trying to figure out how many possible combinations of 6 fighters can be made out of a pool of 22 fighters. These are 1v1 fights (11 fights) so I don’t want any 2 fighters fighting each other to be in the same combination. I imagine it has to be something similar to 22 choose 6 but that wouldn’t account for the fighters against each other. Order does not matter.

Comment: I assume that each fighter is in just a single fight?  So then you have $11$ pairs of fighters and you want to choose six of those pairs, and then one fighter from each of your choices.  Work from there.

Comment: Description is confusing. " 2 fighters fighting each other to be in the same combination."  What does this  mean?

Comment: @herbsteinberg  The way I interpret it (possibly incorrect, of course) is:  The OP wishes to count the ways to choose $6$ fighters out of the possible $22$, subject to the condition that, if fighter $A$ is fighting fighter $B$ then you can not choose *both* $A$ and $B$.  Of course, the OP ought to clarify.  And, as I mentioned in my earlier comment, the OP should clarify whether or not one fighter might be in more than a single match.

Comment: Correct, fighter A is fighting fighter B and you cannot choose both A and B. And yes each fighter only fights once. 

Thanks!

Comment: So, then my first comment sketches a complete answer.  Just follow the hint given there.

Comment: So would it be 11choose6*(2^11)?

Comment: Not quite, because you only need to make the binary choice for the $6$ pairs you selected.

Comment: 11choose6*2 then?

Comment: No...Don't rush.  You have $6$ pairs of shoes.  How many ways can you choose one shoe from each of the $6$ pairs?

Comment: 2^6 so 11choose6*(2^6)

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now, thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

We are assuming that the fighters are paired (with each fighter appearing in exactly one pair).

To choose $6$ of them, subject to the exclusion rule, we first must choose $6$ of the $11$ pairs.  There are, of course, $\binom {11}6$ ways to do that.

Now we must choose $1$ fighter from each of the $6$ pairs we selected.  There are $2^6$ ways to do that.

Combining all this, the answer is $\boxed {\binom {11}6\times 2^6}$.